# Nestjs kafka consumers failed when waiting for reply from each other

Tags: nestjs, microservices, kafka-consumer-api, kafkajs

I'm using Nestjs microservice with Kafka. There are 2 consumers that need data from each other while processing.

In user microservice:

```js
@EventPattern('get_user')
async getUser() {
  const user = { id: 1, name: 'John' };
  const booksByUser = await firstValueFrom(
    this.userClient.send('get_books_by_user', '')
  );

  return { user, books: booksByUser };
}

@MessagePattern('get_author')
getAuthor() {
  return { id: 1, name: 'John' };
}
```

In book microservice:

```js
@EventPattern('get_book')
async getBook() {
  const book = { id: 99, name: 'Lorem ipsum' };
  const author = await firstValueFrom(
    this.paymentClient.send('get_author', '')
  );

  return { book, author };
}

@MessagePattern('get_books_by_user')
getBooksByUser() {
  return [{ id: 99, name: 'Lorem ipsum' }];
}
```

Then I fire `get_user` and `get_book` events at the same time

```js
this.kafkaClient.emit('get_user', '');
this.kafkaClient.emit('get_book', '');
```

Each consumer processes its own message and wait for response from the other one. Both hangs forever and stop sending heartbeat, then eventually get marked as failed by the coordinator

What is the best way to get around this problem. Perhaps I should use another protocol (http/grpc) to replace consumer-to-consumer messaging? Or implement a timeout mechanism? Adding more consumers?

I'm forcing a timeout if a consumer is processing a message longer than 5 seconds, but I dont like it because that means that partition being blocked for too long.